# Error: incompatible types: QuickGame cannot be converted to RoomUpdateListener

Tags: android

I'm implementing some of Google's real-time multiplayer examples for some practice games, and I've run into an error. I'm pretty much just using their code from their website, trying to understand how it works and piece together a working real-time game with a simple waiting room.
However, it's giving me the error described above & I cannot for the life of me understand why. The code where the error originates is below, and Android Studio has underlined the first (this), but offers no further explanation.

```
    private RoomConfig.Builder makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder() {
    return RoomConfig.builder(this)
            .setMessageReceivedListener(this)
            .setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
}
```

The program itself is pretty much just the code found on this page - nothing changed. https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer but if code is requested I will post.

Thanks, I hope it's just something obvious that a newbie like myself overlooked. D:

Comment: You're not implementing `RoomUpdateListener` in your class. Share the first line of your class where you define the name of the class something like `class MyClassName`

Comment: `public class QuickGame extends AppCompatActivity {` this is it. Adding `implements RoomUpdateListener` gives me errors :/

Comment: Yeah, cause you're not overriding the methods of the interface. If you're in Android Studio you can hover over the `RoomUpdateListener` in the implements and press `Alt` + `Enter` and you'll be prompted to add the methods of that interface, click it and it'll automatically be added to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a complete source [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/83dda7c60e13b6c129a8e104437ec69d8a257fa0/BasicSamples/ButtonClicker/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/bc/MainActivity.java)

If you look at the class definition it implements `RoomUpdateListener` all you have to do is change your `Activity` to match. In your example it's

```
public class QuickGame extends AppCompatActivity implements RoomUpdateListener
```

make sure you add the `@Override` methods of the interface into your code. In Android Studio you can hover over the red underline of the interface and press `Alt` + `Enter` and you'll see a menu asking you to implement the methods. Select it, and they'll automatically be added to your code.

You can find all the interface methods [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomUpdateListener) so for example `onJoinedRoom(..)` would look like this in your code

```
@Override
public void onJoinedRoom(int statusCode, Room room) {
    //your code here
}
```